# English.SE pamphlet - hang up or hand out to your friends and classmates

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[Here you go](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37818223/english-pamphlet.pdf)!

Let me know if you think other sites would benefit.

Answer (score 3):

The last sentence is a little confusing:

> If you're an academic, it's a great place to establish a reputation as
>   an expert in the field, apply for funding and sponsorships, and
>   network with other English professionals.

Is English Stack Exchange a good place to apply for funding and sponsorships? If you create a similar document for other Stack Exchange sites, I would suggest clarifying where such funding and sponsorship is available, as it would be of interest to many readers.

Second item: I'm unsure what an English professional is. We are English-language speakers, with varying degrees of proficiency, and of all nationalities. Some of the other Stack Exchange sites are specifically targeted to academicians or research-level experts e.g. Economics Stack Exchange (in public beta) and Mathematics (or maybe Mathematics SO, I don't recall). If you will be producing similarly themed pamphlets for other Stack Exchange sites, do confirm whether the site audience is in fact targeted toward that level of expertise.

Last item: The letterhead and colors were fantastic! I viewed as a PDF in Google Docs,  directly in Adobe Acrobat and as a printout. It looked **so** pretty in all three!

Comment: Well, I just answered part of my own question, which shouldn't have been in an answer anyway, probably. Regarding funding and sponsorships, details are here: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/introducing-the-stack-exchange-research-support-and-fellowship-program