# Promoting English Language & Usage

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This is the near duplicate of [a post](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/promotion-de-french-language-and-usage-promoting-french-language-and-usage) I put on Meta FL&U and [Lauren](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/users/715/lauren) suggested I posted here too.

---

In 2012 the guest of honour of [Expolangues](http://www.expolangues.fr/), an exhibition dedicated to the teaching and learning of languages held in Paris every winter (1–4 February in 2012), is the French language. I suggested we could promote **[FL&U](https://french.stackexchange.com/)** on that occasion. Since this yearly exhibition is essentially visited by teachers and learners from "all" languages would it  sound like a good idea to promote *EL&U* (and other Stack Exchange Language sites) as well?
I'm thinking of posters or leaflets that I would have on the stall I help organize. Unfortunately we won't have an Internet access on the stall, so we'd have to stick to paper.

Comment: If you want to create leaflets, you could model it after [this one](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/english-se-pamphlet-hang-up-or-hand-out-to-your-friends-and-classmates). That one is geared towards the academic promotions we have on English, so we'd have to change the text and example questions for this in order to reflect that it can also be used as a learning site for foreign speakers. But might be useful as a starting off point.

Answer (score 3):

Leaflets (along the lines @Lauren mentioned in a comment) seem like a good idea.  You might also produce some low-cost swag; to me, for a literary audience, bookmarks seem obvious, with each one including one interesting question and a selection of its answers from our site. (Print several different ones; maybe people will compare.)

I was at a conference once where the name badges had a spot for "ask me about", with a place to write in a few words.  People used it for all sorts of informal networking and publicity.  Perhaps attendees from EL&U.SE want to make buttons or badges of that sort.

(I didn't actually answer the "should we" part of your question because I don't know this conference at all.  I think low-effort, low-cost promotion opportunities like I've suggested are pretty much always a good idea, barring conference rules to the contrary.)

Comment: Bookmarks are great and a swell idea to promote any of the Stack Exchange language sites, but however low cost they are to make, they are beyond our means. We couldn't do more than A5 black & white leaflets.

Comment: @Laure: I think she means browser bookmarks. Much cheaper! (Oh, wait ...)

Comment: @Robusto: ha ha.  Um, no. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an adaptation of the text of the [existing leaflet](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/english-se-pamphlet-hang-up-or-hand-out-to-your-friends-and-classmates) ([PDF link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/37818223/english-pamphlet.pdf)) with more emphasis on a teacher audience and a mention of the other language sites. Given the venue, the leaflet should have a French version (on the flip side), which I'm posting on the [French L&U thread](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/promotion-de-french-language-and-usage-promoting-french-language-and-usage/293#293). The English version focuses on ELU while the French version focuses on both ELU and FLU.
Comment welcome, but since the event is very soon, I don't even know if we'll manage to get something printed in time.

---

**English.StackExchange.com** is a community-driven questions and answers site about grammar, etymology, word choice, and usage. It's a great place to ask all your questions about the English language and get answers from the community, as well as to share your own knowledge.

#### Example questions:

Did English ever have a formal version of “you”?
[http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9780](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9780)

Why is “bicycle” pronounced differently from other obviously related words?
[http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26085](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/26085)

Is there a word or phrase for the feeling you get after looking at a word for too long?
[http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6170](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6170)

#### What’s in it for me?

Stack Exchange English is totally free. Questions are answered quickly, so you can use it as a resource when studying or teaching. If you're an academic, it's a great place to establish a reputation as an expert in the field, apply for funding and sponsorships, and network with other English professionals.

#### What about other languages?

Sites about other languages are forming: German, Japanese, French, Spanish and Chinese are already up. Visit http://stackexchange.com/sites to see the full list of Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help and French version @Gilles. Stack Exchange graphic designer made the pdf files and Stack Exchange paid for the flyers to be printed.
I made them publicly available at Expolangues and handed some out as well whenever I could, even to journalists;  this one had his own tour of StackExchange afterwards and wrote an article:
http://www.vousnousils.fr/2012/02/06/la-langue-anglaise-en-questions-reponses-521134

Here are both pdf files:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62542206/english-a5.pdf
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62542206/french-a5.pdf

Comment: Have these flyers been deleted?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe   They are somewhat outdated (mainly because of the existence of ELL) but I can make them available again if asked.

Comment: I see. I was asking about them to get some inspiration for a flyer for Language Learning Stack Exchange (and possibly some other language-related SE sites).